# How to Copy Files from a Isolated VM on an ESX Server

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, file-sharing

We have a Sandbox built on a ESXi (5.0) server and have a VM((A Domain Controller) on it.

I want to copy the files on that VM to my workstation. Is there anyway to do that?

I can browse the data store of the ESX server. Can the Files on VM transferred to the datastore?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the actual VM itself, such as the vmdk files or just files within the VM's Guest OS?

Comment: Can you temporarily enable networking?

Comment: @Cole The files  and documents inside VM.

Comment: @ewwhite that would be a complete disaster and screw up active directory for the organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transfer the files within the VMDK to the datastore directly, or to your hard drive.  You may be able to mount a copy of the VMDK file in Windows to access the files using the [VMware Disk Mount Utility](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=Disk%20Mount%20Utility%205.5%20Driver%20Tools&productId=46).